# How can I specify the parameter for POST requests while using APIView with django-rest-swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-2.0

In the latest version on Django REST Swagger (2.1.0) YAML docstrings have been deprecated. I cannot get swagger to show the POST request parameters.

Here is my view

```
class UserAuthenticationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserAuthenticationSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            return Response({'token': user.auth_token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Here is my Serializer

```
class UserAuthenticationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get('username')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:

                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = 'User account is disabled.'
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

            else:
                msg = 'Unable to log in with provided credentials.'
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        else:
            msg = 'Must include "username" and "password".'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

This is what I get in my generated [image]

I do not get a form with the fields for the POST data. How do I get that?

Comment: Any ideas about same but for GET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the rest framework get schema code (the part of it):

```
def get_serializer_fields(self, path, method, view):
    """
    Return a list of `coreapi.Field` instances corresponding to any
    request body input, as determined by the serializer class.
    """
    if method not in ('PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST'):
        return []

    if not hasattr(view, 'get_serializer'):
        return []

    serializer = view.get_serializer()

    if isinstance(serializer, serializers.ListSerializer):
        return [
            coreapi.Field(
                name='data',
                location='body',
                required=True,
                type='array'
            )
        ]
...
```

As you can see - it should work if you define the `get_serializer` method on your view - which returns the `UserAuthenticationSerializer`.

-- EDIT --

Forget: Happy Coding.

Answer (score 29):

**django-rest-swagger** uses **rest_framework.schemas.SchemaGenerator** to generate the schema and **SchemaGenerator** uses **get_serializer_fields** to get the serializer information of a view. get_serializer_fields checks if a view has a **get_serializer** method to generate the form. **GenericAPIView** provides the **get_serializer** so inheriting from it is enough.

Inherit view from `GenericAPIView` rather than simple `APIView`. And add `serializer_class` attribute with appropriate serializer

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView 

class UserAuthenticationView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserAuthenticationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserAuthenticationSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            return Response({'token': user.auth_token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)    
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: What can be the possible way to do it for function based views?

Comment: Wow, this worked for me, I switched from APIView to GenericAPIView and swagger auto-detected all fields in the serializer

Answer (score 2):

A working example for a custom ViewSet, with django-rest-swagger==2.2.0:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema
from rest_framework.compat import coreapi, coreschema
from rest_framework.decorators import action


class DeviceViewSchema(AutoSchema):
    """
    Schema customizations for DeviceViewSet
    """

    def get_manual_fields(self, path, method):
        extra_fields = []
        if path.endswith('/send_command/'):
            extra_fields = [
                coreapi.Field(
                    "command",
                    required=True,
                    location="form",
                    schema=coreschema.String()
                ),
                coreapi.Field(
                    "params",
                    required=False,
                    location="form",
                    schema=coreschema.String()
                ),
            ]
        manual_fields = super().get_manual_fields(path, method)
        return manual_fields + extra_fields


class DeviceViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'channel'
    lookup_value_regex = '[\w-]+'

    schema = DeviceViewSchema()

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True, url_name='send_command')
    def send_command(self, request, channel):
        """
        Send command to device

        Parameters:
        - command: string
        - params: string (JSON encoded list or dict)
        """
        ...
```

The final result is:

[image]

Comment: What is @action?

Comment: ```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
```

I include the missing import to the code snippet